# Unable to see territory in salesforce free edition

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to see a user territory salesforce free edition but I'm unable to.

How do I enable, setup, and use territory management in Salesforce?

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure what you mean by the free edition (Trial?) however, according to the Salesforce comparison chart, Territory management is only in Enterprise edition and up

Also, do you mean Territory Management? Or something else?

http://www.salesforce.com/crm/editions-pricing.jsp

If you are on the Trial Version of Enterprise edition, you will need that this feature will be enabled for you: http://eu1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/territories_enable.htm

quoted: 
**Territory management is not enabled by default in Salesforce. To request territory management for your organization, contact salesforce.com.**